# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $S=N, A=P(N), \mu= h dv$ with $v$ being the counting measure with

$$h(k)=\frac{1}{4^k}, \quad \text{and}$$
$$f_n(k)=(\frac{k}{n}-2)^k 1_{(1,2,3,...,n)}(k),$$

Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu$.

My ideas:

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu \\
=& \lim_{n \to \infty} \int (\frac{k}{n}-2)^k 1_{(1,2,3,...,n}(k)\frac{1}{4^k}dv \\
=&\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} (\frac{k}{n}-2)^k \frac{1}{4^k}
\end{align}
$$

This looks for me like an alternating sum that should be convergent using Leibnitz Rule? But I have problems getting rid of the $k/n$ fraction.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Notice that $\lim_nf_n(x)=(-1)^x2^x$ for each $x\in\mathbb{N}$,  and that
$$|f_n|=\big(2-\frac{x}{n}\big)^x\mathbf{1}_{\{1,\ldots, n\}}(x)\leq 2^x\mathbf{1}_{\{1,\ldots,n\}}(x)$$

Since $\int_\mathbb{N}2^x\mu(dx)=\sum_n(1/2)^n<\infty$, you can apply dominated convergence.